# Python - print value to new file?

Tags: python

```
import sys
import pickle
import string

def Menu():
    print ("\n***********MENU************")
    print ("0. Quit")
    print ("1. Read text file")
    print ("2. Display counts")
    print ("3. Display statistics of word lengths")
    print ("4. Print statistics to file")

def Loop():
    choice = -1

    while choice !=0:
        Menu()
        choice = (int(input("Please choose 1-4 to perform function. Press 0 to exit the program. Thank you. \n")))
        if choice == 0:
            print ("Exit program. Thank you.")
            sys.exit
        elif choice == 1:
                user_File = ReadTextFile()
        elif choice == 2:
                DisplayCounts(user_File)
        elif choice == 3:
                DisplayStats(user_File)
        elif choice == 4:
                PrintStats(aDictionary)     
        else: 
            print ("Error.")

def ReadTextFile():
    print "\n" 
    while True:
            InputFile = input("Please enter a file name (NOTE: must have quotation marks around name and extension): ")
        if (InputFile.lower().endswith('.txt')):
                break
        else:
                print("That was an incorrect file name. Please try again.")
        continue
    return InputFile

def DisplayCounts(InputFile): 
    print "\n"   
    numCount = 0
    dotCount = 0
    commaCount = 0
    lineCount = 0
    wordCount = 0

    with open(InputFile, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                wordCount+=len(line.split())
                lineCount+=1
                for char in line:
                        if char.isdigit() == True:
                            numCount+=1
                        elif char == '.':
                            dotCount+=1
                        elif char == ',':
                            commaCount+=1

    print("Number count: " + str(numCount))
    print("Comma count: " + str(commaCount))
    print("Dot count: " + str(dotCount))
    print("Line count: " + str(lineCount))
    print("Word count: " + str(wordCount))

def DisplayStats(InputFile):
    print "\n"
    temp1 = []
    temp2 = []
    lengths = []
    myWords = []
    keys = []
    values = []
    count = 0

    with open(InputFile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                temp2.append(word)
                temp1.append(len(word))

        for x in temp1:
            if x not in lengths:
                lengths.append(x)

    lengths.sort()

    dictionaryStats = {}
    for x in lengths:
        dictionaryStats[x] = []

    for x in lengths:
        for word in temp2:
            if len(word) == x:
                dictionaryStats[x].append(word)

    for key in dictionaryStats: 
            print("Key = " + str(key) + " Total number of words with " + str(key) + " characters = " + str(len(dictionaryStats[key])))        
    return dictionaryStats

def PrintStats(aDictionary):
    print "\n"
    aFile = open("statsWords.dat", 'w')
    for key in aDictionary:
        aFile.write(str(key) + " : " +  str(aDictionary[key]) + "\n")        
    aFile.close()


Loop()
```

There's something with that last function that is really tripping me up. I keep getting errors. I know `aDictionary` is not defined but I do not even know what to define it as! Any of you guys have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe for option 4 you want to do the same as option 3, except print to a file instead of to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("some_file.txt","W") as f:
    print >> f, "Something goes here!"
```

its hard to say without your errors. .. but you almost certainly need to have aDictionary defined

also probably something like

```
def DisplayCounts(InputFile): 
    print "\n"   
    numCount = 0
    dotCount = 0
    commaCount = 0
    lineCount = 0
    wordCount = 0

    with open(InputFile, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                wordCount+=len(line.split())
                lineCount+=1
                for char in line:
                        if char.isdigit() == True:
                            numCount+=1
                        elif char == '.':
                            dotCount+=1
                        elif char == ',':
                            commaCount+=1

    return dict(numbers=numCount,
    comma=commaCount,
    dot=dotCount,
    line=lineCount,
    word=wordCount)

result = DisplayCounts("someinput.txt")
print result
```